# svn merge on renamed files

Tags: svn, merge, mv

First I make a branch from the main project

```
$ svn cp project branched
```

Then I rename some files in the branch:

```
$ svn mv branched/file.c branched/file.cpp
```

After commit/update, somebody else makes changes to the original file in the original project, how can I merge those changes ?

```
$ svn merge project/file.c branched/file.cpp
svn: E195002: Invalid merge source 'project/file.c'; a working copy path can only be used with a repository revision (a number, a date, or head)
```

Is it only a syntax problem, or as a colleague is suggesting, a deeper problem making it basically impossible to keep renamed files in sync ? If so what is the correct approach to renaming files and keeping them in sync ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Invalid merge source 'project/file.c'; a working copy path can only
>   be used with a repository revision"

Let's break that down.

> "Invalid merge source 'project/file.c'"

SVN is having a problem understanding what you mean by "project/file.c". Note SVN is attempting to use the same file you told it to use, and this file apparently exists on your system. No problems with the rename here.

> "a working copy path"

You're telling SVN to merge from a file that already exists on your machine in your working copy. This is NOT the normal use. Normally, you specify a repository URL to merge from. This use *is* supported, but:

> "can only be used with a repository revision"

...if you try merging from a working copy, you you're actually only telling SVN what file you're talking about, and SVN will still use the repository server to get the data for the merge. Thus you need to tell SVN what version to merge. E.g.:

```
$ svn merge -r HEAD project/file.c branched/file.cpp
```

HOWEVER, the other weird thing you're doing here is merging a single file. Normally you want to merge entire directory trees, not individual files. So, I'd recommend a variation on the following instead:

```
$ svn merge http://example.com/svn/path/to/project branched
```

Read up on merges here:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.merge.html

Comment: 1. Merging subtrees is **not weird** here, in this specific case, without such merge, merging the whole trees later will produce "Tree conflict" 2. `-r HEAD` in merge is excessive (HEAD is default value for merges)

Comment: It mostly makes sense, but I tried your last example: `$ svn merge https://.../project/ branch/file_util.cpp`
svn: E195016: 'https://.../project@5650' must be ancestrally related to 'https://.../branch/file.cpp@5650'

Comment: Oops, typo. Fixing now.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, although I'm sure I tried it yesterday and got an error... Although I think I was trying to use the '^'.

Comment: The problem yesterday was that I gave a command that said "merge the entire trunk directory into this one specific file" which obviously should not work. But it's fixed in the answer now to use two directories.